# Defined a function that can be called as an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have a function.

```
function obj(id){
    if (this.__proto__.constructor !== i) {
        return new i(id);
    }
    this.element = (typeof id === 'string') ? document.getElementById(id) : id;
    this.remove = function(){
        this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element);
    }
    this.cookie = function (name,value,expire){
        var now = new Date();
        var time = now.getTime();
        time += expire*1000; //in second
        now.setTime(time);
        document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; expires=' + now.toUTCString() + '; path=/';
    }
}
```

I can easily call method `remove` like `obj("someid").remove();`, but method `cookie`. Function cookie does not depend on `id`.

How could I define object `obj` in order to call its methods with both ways `obj(id).remove()` and `obj.cookie()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
function obj(id) {
    if (!(this instanceof obj)) return new obj(id);

    this.element = (typeof id === 'string') ? document.getElementById(id) : id;
}
obj.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element);
};
obj.cookie = function(name,value,expire) {
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    time += expire*1000; //in second
    now.setTime(time);
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; expires=' + now.toUTCString() + '; path=/';
};
```

A function (like `obj`) *is* an object, so you can simply add properties (like `.cookie`) to it.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you.